# Border out DIV (borde fuera de div)

Tags: html, css, margin, padding

I have problems in CSS with the property Padding or Border. I have an image within a div that fits perfect, but to add margin exceeds the div that contains it.

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row" />
    <div class="ima">
        <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
        <img class="img" src="https://sites.google.com/site/cnetuc/imagen-04.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas laoreet mattis arcu eget euismod. Donec eget purus et enim cursus feugiat sit amet in diam.
            <p>
    </div>
    <div class="ima">
        <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
        <img class="img" src="https://sites.google.com/site/cnetuc/imagen-04.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas laoreet mattis arcu eget euismod. Donec eget purus et enim cursus feugiat sit amet in diam.
            <p>
    </div>
    <div class="ima">
        <h1>Titulo 1</h1>
        <img class="img" src="https://sites.google.com/site/cnetuc/imagen-04.jpg" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas laoreet mattis arcu eget euismod. Donec eget purus et enim cursus feugiat sit amet in diam.
            <p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Attached [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ismaelivan/soqjpv7r/)

Comment: does `box-sizing: border-box;` work for you?

Comment: Thanks cocoa, if it works!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` to the image.

```
.ima img{
  width:100%;
  border:10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Or

```
width: calc(100% - 20px);
```

Comment: mmm interesting function